# Hash of Hash of Array (autovivification ??)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have done [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) for quite a long time and hence this is confusing me to no end in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby). I am gathering below data from various places and want to put in below format:

```
{
   :"user_100" => {
      :user_policy => [
         "userpolicy_100",
         "userpolicy_200"
      ],
      :group_policy => [
         "grouppolicy_300",
         "grouppolicy_400"
      ],
   },
   :"user_200" => {
      :user_policy => [
         "userpolicy_300",
         "userpolicy_400"
      ],
      :group_policy => [
         "grouppolicy_300",
         "grouppolicy_400"
      ],
   },
}
```

Above structure is hash of hash of array and I am just not able to get this working in ruby. BTW, I have written above code manually and hence syntax errors may exist.

I tried:

```
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

but this would work only when I have `nested hashes` and `no array` down the road.

Then I tried:

```
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

but this would work only for `hash of arrays` and not for `hash of hash of array`.

I need to capture this data in one single place and I would imagine doing it perl way as displayed in above code snippet.

**Question:**

1. How to create `hash of hash of array` in ruby?
2. Is there a more generic way of initializing any deep nested hash/array combination?
3. OR Am I not thinking in a RUBY'ish way and is there a better way of addressing my fundamental problem?

**UPDATE:**

This is my actual code:

```
array_users = Array.new
hash_user_polices = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }

iam = Aws::IAM.new

iam.list_users().each do |resp|
  resp.users.each do |x|
    array_users << x.user_name
  end
end

array_users.each do |user|
  iam.list_user_policies(:user_name => user).each do |resp|
    resp.each do |x|
      x.policy_names.each do |y|
        hash_user_polices[:"#{user}"] << y.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So,

1. I get the users list and put it in `array_users`. Then I get the respective user policies which are returned as an `array` (hence I am iterating `x.policy_names.each do |y|`).
2. I really wanted to have `hash_user_polices[:"#{user}"][:user_policy] << y.to_s`.
3. But due to my limited expertise in ruby, I could make it work only with `hash_user_polices[:"#{user}"] << y.to_s` only after defining it as `hash_user_polices = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }`.
4. I will be writing a separate piece of code to get the group_policies and hence at that time, I would like it to have `hash_user_polices[:"#{user}"][:group_policy] << y.to_s`.

In short, I'm fetching `user list`, `user policy` and `group policy` in three different API calls and struggling to consolidate these three in a single place so that I can make some sense out of it.

Comment: It all depends on the structure of data source(s). Could you show them as well?

Comment: @BroiSatse, Please find the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is always hash.hash.array, you could use the combination of your two attempts:

```
hash = Hash.new do |oh,ok|
  oh[ok] = Hash.new do |ih,ik|
    ih[ik] = []
  end
end
```

Personally I wouldn't be using Hashes and Arrays to do this; ruby has a very strong object model, I'd create classes for each level of nesting (particularly the "user" level, which appears to have a well-defined set of attributes). you might find that a bit of overkill, though.

Comment: yeah, I can't think of any other way than hashes/arrays as that's fairly simple in perl and I have done it for years. I know that Ruby folks do not use nested hashes/arrays as much as perl folks do. Just that I do not know what would be a better way of achieving the same in ruby.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation which will be helpful for me to understand how this can be achieved using classes. +1.

Comment: I created a gist to hopefully illustrate my thought process in refactoring. I've only gone so far in the gist. You can take from it as much as you need: https://gist.github.com/phluid61/8933665

Comment: Thanks for writing sample code explaining different approach. I certainly know a bit more ruby after reading your gist. Thanks. And yes, the other two approaches you mentioned work too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this (however it is hard to say without knowing how your data is structured)

```
iam = Aws::IAM.new

array_users = iam.list_users.map(&:users).flatten.map(&:user_name)

Hash[
  array_users.map do |user|
    [
      user.to_sym,
      { user_policy: iam.list_user_policies(:user_name => user).map(&:resp).flatten.map(&:policy_names).flatten.map(&:to_s),
        group_policy: <group_policy logic>
      }
    [        
  end
end ]
```

Comment: I am trying to make your code work as it complaining about no method exist and also correcting a couple of syntax errors. In the mean while, could you explain what it is doing?

Answer (score 1):

How about you split your code into something more understandable until it becomes easy for you?

```
def add_policy(hash, user, policy)
  # create a subhash for the user key if the hash doesn't exist
  hash[user] ||= {}

  # get the policy key: :group_policy or :user_policy
  # if policy_key can not be determined from the policy, 
  # you could pass an extra param for the policy_key
  policy_key = ( policy.include?("group") ? :group_policy : :user_policy )

  # create an array for the user's policy if none exists
  hash[user][policy_key] ||= []

  # push the policy into the array
  hash[user][policy_key] << policy

  hash
end



h = {}
add_policy(h, "user_100", "userpolicy_100")
add_policy(h, "user_100", "userpolicy_200")
add_policy(h, "user_100", "grouppolicy_300")
add_policy(h, "user_100", "grouppolicy_400")
add_policy(h, "user_200", "userpolicy_300")
add_policy(h, "user_200", "userpolicy_400")
add_policy(h, "user_200", "grouppolicy_300")
add_policy(h, "user_200", "grouppolicy_400")

=> {"user_100"=>
  {:user_policy=>["userpolicy_100", "userpolicy_200"],
   :group_policy=>["grouppolicy_300", "grouppolicy_400"]},
 "user_200"=>
  {:user_policy=>["userpolicy_300", "userpolicy_400"],
   :group_policy=>["grouppolicy_300", "grouppolicy_400"]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a different approach. It works perfectly. However, I will be accepting @Matty's answer (which he had provided in [gist](https://gist.github.com/phluid61/8933665)) as it was earlier in chronological order. +1 nonetheless for your time and effort.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer haha, sure, no prob :-) Thanks for being considerate, rare to see on SO!